# Common type for Query or DBIOAction

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I'm trying to pass a query or action as a parameter to a method. The reason is I want to run the same actions on the result of different queries on the same table.

For example:

```
val query1 = listItems   
val query2 = listItems.filter { x => x.id===1 }
```

And my method:

```
private def findListItems(query: Query[???]): Future[Foo] = {  ... }
```

Turns I can't just pass query1 or query2 because they have different types (this is what my ide auto completes):

```
val query1: TableQuery[ListItems] = listItems
val query2: Query[ListItems, ListItems.TableElementType, Seq] = listItems.filter(_.listId===1)
```

Where moreover the ListItems in ListItems.TableElementType causes a compiler error: "not found: value ListItems".

I also tried to pass the action instead of the query to see if I have more luck, but this was not the case. The type is the same but ListItems.TableElementType still shows the error "not found: value ListItems".

```
val action1: DBIOAction[Seq[ListItems.TableElementType], ListItems.TableElementType, Effect.Read] = query1.result 
val action2: DBIOAction[Seq[ListItems.TableElementType], ListItems.TableElementType, Effect.Read] = query2.result
```

How can I pass these queries or actions as parameter to a common method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard not having the table definition, but I believe that you can pass both queries by having as a parameter type something like this:

```
private def findListItems(query: Query[ListItems, _, Seq]): Future[Foo] = {  ... }
```

The `_` in there should work but you can make it explicit by using the proper type of your table (i.e. the one you pass to the `Table` constructor when you extend it in your definition).

You can achieve the same with DBIOs, just use `DBIO[YourType]` as the parameter type (where again `YourType` is the type that you are mapping in the table definition).

Comment: Ah, thanks! The wildcard type doesn't work because I'm accessing the fields (without casting). The problem was that my type is (Int, String, Int, Int, Boolean, String, String, String) - autocomplete doesn't seem to be capable to determine this. And for some reason I didn't think this is TableElementType though it makes totally sense.